# How can the roots of a (homogenous) polynomial over ring $Z_N$ help me factorize $N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cryptography

I am solving a problem where the problem is asking me illustrate how I can factorize $N$ if I know the roots of a homogenous polynomial $F$ over the ring $Z_N$. How can I proceed to do so?